# error while doing summary on tobit: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r

I used to use a tobit regression with the following code:

```
tobit56 <- tobit (months56 ~ g1v3 + gender + un30min, left=0, right=60, data=gym)
summary(tobit56)
```

That code always worked well for me and got me a summary of the tobit.

Since yesterday whenever I run this, I get an error after I do summary:

```
tobit56 <- tobit (months56 ~ g1v3 + gender + un30min, left=0, right=60, data=gym)
summary(tobit56)
```

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Somebody has any idea what can cause this error message?

Comment: What is the `str` of gym?

Comment: Gym is a whole dataset with many variables. when I do str on gym, this is what it shows.                                               
    Classes 'tbl_df', 'tbl' and 'data.frame': 213 obs. of  256 variables:

Comment: Yes but this error is basically saying you have a vector in there. what is the `str(summary(...))`?

Comment: Can you provide a subset of your data (ideally using `dput(head(gym,X))` where X is enough data to replicate the problem?

Comment: He just says the same problem when I try to do that code. -->> str(summary(tobit56))
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Unfortunately you got some debugging advice that was predictably doomed to fail. As you found out the same error would be expected from a call to `str(summary(tobit56))` as occurred with `summary(tobit56)`. Further, the fact that you failed to include that package for the function `tobit` and not offering a [MCVE] is likely to have caused many viewers to ignore the question. The error is not at all likely to be helpful since it so "generic". Almost an infinite array of coding mistakes could trigger that message. It's a classic result of failing to use  "["  for extraction inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the [`summary.tobit`](https://rdrr.io/cran/AER/src/R/tobit.R) function of `AER` package.

Solution 1:

```
class(tobit_model$y) <- "Surv"
summary(tobit_model)
```

Solution 2:
Commenting out the line `if(!inherits(y, "Surv")) y <- y$y` and the function works fine.

`summary.tobit(tobit_model)`

```
summary.tobit <- function(object, correlation = FALSE, symbolic.cor = FALSE, vcov. = NULL, ...) 
{
  ## failure
  if(!is.null(object$fail)) {
    warning("tobit/survreg failed.", object$fail, "   No summary provided\n")
    return(invisible(object))
  }
  
  ## rank
  if(all(is.na(object$coefficients))) {
    warning("This model has zero rank --- no summary is provided")
    return(invisible(object))
  }
  
  ## vcov
  if(is.null(vcov.)) vcov. <- vcov(object)
  else {
    if(is.function(vcov.)) vcov. <- vcov.(object)
  }
  
  ## coefmat
  coef <- coeftest(object, vcov. = vcov., ...)
  attr(coef, "method") <- NULL
  
  ## Wald test
  nc <- length(coef(object))
  has_intercept <- attr(terms(object), "intercept") > 0.5
  wald <- if(nc <= has_intercept) NULL else linearHypothesis(object,
                                                             if(has_intercept) cbind(0, diag(nc-1)) else diag(nc),
                                                             vcov. = vcov.)[2,3]
  ## instead of: waldtest(object, vcov = vcov.)
  
  ## correlation
  correlation <- if(correlation) cov2cor(vcov.) else NULL
  
  ## distribution
  dist <- object$dist
  if(is.character(dist)) sd <- survreg.distributions[[dist]]
  else sd <- dist
  if(length(object$parms)) pprint <- paste(sd$name, "distribution: parmameters =", object$parms)
  else pprint <- paste(sd$name, "distribution")
  
  ## number of observations
  ## (incorporating "bug fix" change for $y in survival 2.42-7)
  surv_table <- function(y) {
    # if(!inherits(y, "Surv")) y <- y$y
    type <- attr(y, "type")
    if(is.null(type) || (type == "left" && any(y[, 2L] > 1))) type <- "old"
    y <- switch(type,    
                "left" = 2 - y[, 2L],
                "interval" = y[, 3L],
                y[, 2L]
    )
    table(factor(y, levels = c(2, 1, 0, 3),
                 labels = c("Left-censored", "Uncensored", "Right-censored", "Interval-censored")))
  }
  nobs <- surv_table(object$y)
  nobs <- c("Total" = sum(nobs), nobs[1:3])
  
  rval <- object[match(c("call", "df", "loglik", "iter", "na.action", "idf", "scale"),
                       names(object), nomatch = 0)]
  rval <- c(rval, list(coefficients = coef, correlation = correlation,
                       symbolic.cor = symbolic.cor, parms = pprint, n = nobs, wald = wald))
  
  class(rval) <- "summary.tobit"
  return(rval)
}
```